# SQL Query Not Displaying as Expected

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to find where customers have not made any transactions, by joining two tables Customer and Transaction. However, I get no values returned with my query.

```
SELECT
[CUST].[CustID],
[CUST].[CustName]
FROM [Cust]
INNER JOIN [TRANS]
ON [CUST].[CustID] = [TRANS].[CustID]
WHERE [CUST].[CustID] != [TRANS].[CustID]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are joining on

```
[CUST].[CustID] = [TRANS].[CustID]
```

but the where clause says

```
[CUST].[CustID] != [TRANS].[CustID]
```

if you want the list of costumers with no transaction you should use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
[CUST].[CustID],
[CUST].[CustName]
FROM [Cust]
LEFT JOIN [TRANS]
ON [CUST].[CustID] = [TRANS].[CustID]
WHERE [TRANS].[CustID] is null
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is the same as doing:

```
SELECT [CUST].[CustID],
       [CUST].[CustName]
FROM [Cust]
INNER JOIN [TRANS]
    ON [CUST].[CustID] = [TRANS].[CustID] AND [CUST].[CustID] != [TRANS].[CustID]
```

This will obviously never happen, hence the result with no rows.

To get the customers with no transactions you should do:

```
SELECT [CUST].[CustID],
       [CUST].[CustName]
FROM [Cust]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM [TRANS]
                  WHERE [CUST].[CustID] = [TRANS].[CustID]
                 )
```